# path setting difficulty in djnago urls file

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

MyProject urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('HappyHomes/', include('HappyHomes.urls')),
    path('HappyHomesAdmin/', include('HappyHomesAdmin.urls')),
]
```

HappyHomes urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from HappyHomes import views

app_name = "HappyHomes"

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index),
    path('login/', views.login),
    path('logincheck/', views.logincheck),
    path('logout/', views.logout),
    path('registration/', views.registration),
    path('reg/', views.reg),
    path('profile/', views.profile),
    path('edit_profile/', views.edit_profile),
    path('pg_hostel_showall/', views.pg_hostel_showall),
    path('pg_hostel/', views.pg_hostel),
    path('pg_hostel_booking/', views.pg_hostel_booking),
]
```

HappyHomesAdmin urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from HappyHomesAdmin import views

app_name = "HappyHomesAdmin"

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name="home"),
    path('addnew/', views.addnew),
]
```

my views.py file of HappyHomes app

```
def registration(request):
    return render(request, 'registration.html')

def reg(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('HappyHomesAdmin:home'))
```

Also, there are many more functions. None of them is working. I have to write manually everthing in URL.

Now if I am trying to jump from MyProject to HappyHomes in browser like this way **http://127.0.0.1:8000/HappyHomes/** it doesn't show me the functions of HappyHomes urls file. It show me same result. With 2 apps and 1 admin site. 
So if i write **http://127.0.0.1:8000** or **http://127.0.0.1:8000/HappyHomes** there is no difference because it shows the same result. I dont know how to solve this.

Comment: **I have edited my question and make changes so everyone can be clear about it. Somebody can please reopen my question.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your folder that has same name of your project, i think is MyProject, inside the urls.py you need to set a path, as below

In urls.py of your project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    path('app2/', include('app2.urls')),
    path('app3/', include('app3.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

You have to define your app name in the urls.py file of your app, for example:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "app1" #example

urlpatterns = [...]
```

in a views.py of a app, for example app2, you can just:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect, reverse
    def example(request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app1:home'))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. So there will be 3 urls file right? 1st will be in project itself and other two will be in application folder right? Also may i know how to set path of applications in urls file of MyProject?

Comment: Yes, each application will have a url.py file + the url.py of the project itself. I will edit my anwser to show how set path to your apps :)

Comment: yes. i did it tha same way but i am getting error in ```path('', include('main.urls')),``` line of main urls file of MyProject

Comment: When I start server I can see like this ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/``` with my app names **HappyHomes and HappyHomesAdmin** and **admin**.
When I wrote like this ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/HappyHomes``` and try to jump in to files of **HappyHomes** I still get the same result. I dont see any of my path files of my **HappyHomes** app which i have declare itself in a urls file of **HappyHomes**. While I get this **The current path, HappyHomes, didn't match any of these.**  I have made some mistakes in path but dont know where.

Comment: Can you update your question and post your urls files?

Comment: Yeah Sure. I will do it

Comment: I see two strange things in your code, first is the import in views "from HappyHomesAdmin import views", try: "from . import views"m and the other thing is url with uppercase letters, i don't know if this works because i never saw that, every url that i see is in lowercase

Comment: I solved that problem. Actually mistake was in html file when I was redirecting. Instead of writing this ```href="/HappyHomes/index/"``` I was writing like this way. ```href="/index/"``` that's why it was not redirecting.